# I'd like to know how to use "otherwise" and "other than that"

Tags: word-choice

These are my sentences.

> This week I've been busy preparing for my test.
>  I study  5hours and do the household chores about two hours every day.  
> For the rest of the time I just take it easy, watching TV or reading.

I'd like to know if I can change "for the rest of the time" to "otherwise" or "other than that", like "Otherwise I just take it easy." or "Other than that I just take it easy."  I did research myself, but I wasn't sure about it.  Could you explain it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Other than that" can be substituted here, but not "otherwise."

"Otherwise" is generally to express consequences to conditional statements (synonymous with "or else"). For example:

> Bob had better study for his test, otherwise he'll fail.

It can also be used to mean "differently" or "anything else." For example:

> Bob will fail his exam because he didn't study. He shouldn't expect otherwise.

"Other than that" usually means "separately," or "in addition to that" and can't be substituted into the above sentences. It's mostly used between ideas that have no direct connection, or as a final "catch-all" when listing items or actions.

Comment: I thought that in your first example I could use both.  I also thought both are sometimes interchangeable. But I'm wrong.  Thank you very much.